# Change imagebutton resource onclick

Tags: android, onclick, imagebutton

I would like to change the image associated with an `ImageButton` onClick. I'm trying to do it like this but it does not work:

```
ImageButton play;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi = convertView;
    if (vi == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
    play = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.imagePlay);

    play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    play.invalidate();

        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(isPlaying){  
                    mMediaPlayer.stop();  
                    mMediaPlayer.release();
                    mMediaPlayer = null;
                    play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                    play.invalidate();
                    isPlaying = false;
                }
                else{
                    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, songs[position]);                
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                    isPlaying = true;
                    play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                    play.invalidate();

                    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            isPlaying = false;
                            play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                            play.invalidate();

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

This way, the image stays as a play button and never change in pause button. How can i fix that?

Comment: What do you mean when you say onCompletion() doesn't work?
Is the image not changed?
Or is the onComplete() never called?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `ImageButton play` outside your getView method. And with every row you add, you are assigning a new ImageButton to it (the one from the row that is added).

When your `onClick(View v)` method is then fired, `play` is the last button added. So assign the button you clicked on to `play` first inside the `onClick()` method.

```
ImageButton play;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // SAME

        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                play = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imagePlay);

                if(isPlaying){  
                    // SAME
                }
                else{
                    // SAME
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine but this way onCompletion() still doesn't change the resource assigned. Is it possible to fix it?